# Elasticsearch bool query with OR condition returns only the single element

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to create bool OR query, that returns multifield match with slops. I need to find **all** results that satisfy the defined slop value

```
# ---------------------------------------------------
# Create demo index
# ---------------------------------------------------
PUT /slop-search-001
```

For example, I have phrases with `foo`, `bar` and `baz` values, divided by one, two or three words.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------
# Put documents 1, 2, 3
# ---------------------------------------------------
POST /slop-search-001/_doc/1
{
  "foobar": "foo one bar",
  "barbaz": "bar one baz",
  "bazfoo": "baz one foo"
}

POST /slop-search-001/_doc/2
{
  "foobar": "foo one two bar",
  "barbaz": "bar one two baz",
  "bazfoo": "baz one two foo"
}

POST /slop-search-001/_doc/3
{
  "foobar": "foo one two three bar",
  "barbaz": "bar one two three baz",
  "bazfoo": "baz one two three foo"
}
```

I've created a bool query nester OR condition using `should` with span_near queries:

```
GET /slop-search-001/_search
GET /slop-search-001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "foobar": {
                        "value": "foo"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "foobar": {
                        "value": "bar"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "in_order": true,
            "slop": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "barbaz": {
                        "value": "bar"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "barbaz": {
                        "value": "baz"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "in_order": true, 
            "slop": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "bazfoo": {
                        "value": "baz"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "bazfoo": {
                        "value": "foo"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "in_order": true,
            "slop": 3
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "post_tags": [
      "</mark>"
    ],
    "pre_tags": [
      "<mark>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "foobar": {},
      "barbaz": {},
      "bazfoo": {}
    }
  }
}
```

What do I expect from search:

1. Find no matches if every slop is 0
2. Find only the document #1 if every slop is 1
3. Find documents #1 and #2 if every slop is 2
4. Find all three documents if every slop is 3 or greater

When I'm executing the search it seems that slop works partially - if I set every slop to 0 - I don't get any match.

But If the slop is obviously greater (like 4) - I get only the first document.

I can't get what's going wrong and why do I always receive a single result? Could anyone help me please to find, what's wrong with the query?

**Update:** it was about document put data - I used the wrong mapping. Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. The query works as it should. I was creating documents with wrong fields.